# div style messed up when zooming in

Tags: html, css

heres my project and i've been having a hard time trying to figure out the reason why this div "leftCardapio", whenever its zoomed in, the elements inside of it increase their height and width.
i have no ideia what this may be, can someone please gimme a hand?
appreciate the help.

here is my full projecttt
[image: and here is the "leftCardapio" div im talking about]

```css
/* Variables */

:root {
    --Gray: #323a3a;
    --DarkBlue: #123B79;
    --LightBlue: #18A5A7;
    --LightGray: #D9D9D9;
    --White: white;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}


/* Order:
Bottom,
Left,
Top,
Content,
Container
 */


/* Container DIV*/

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#img_Content {
    height: 97%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}


/* Bottom DIV */

.bottom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}


/* LEFT DIV */

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    column-gap: 10px;
    background-color: var(--Gray);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}

.itemDestaque,
.itemCardapio,
.itemBebidas,
.itemReservar_mesa {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 1;
}

.itemDestaque {
    margin-top: 33%;
}

.itemDestaque,
.itemCardapio,
.itemBebidas,
.itemReservar_mesa span {
    font-weight: 550;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}

.itemCardapio:hover,
.itemDestaque:hover,
.itemBebidas:hover,
.itemReservar_mesa:hover {
    box-shadow: 5px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: var(--LightBlue);
}

#destaqueIMG,
#cardapioIMG,
#bebidasIMG,
#reservar_mesaIMG {
    height: 80%;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    object-fit: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#bebidasIMG {
    width: 30%;
}


/* LEFT CARDAPIO DIV   */

.leftCardapio {
    display: none;
}

.itemCardapio:hover>.leftCardapio {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}

.itemPratos,
.itemSaladas,
.itemSopas,
.itemSobremesas,
.itemMolhos,
.itemPorcoes {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}

.itemPratos:hover,
.itemSaladas:hover,
.itemSopas:hover,
.itemSobremesas:hover,
.itemMolhos:hover,
.itemPorcoes:hover {
    background-color: var(--DarkBlue);
}


/* LEFT BEBIDAS DIV  */

.leftBebidas {
    display: none;
}

.itemBebidas:hover>.leftBebidas {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}

.itemBebida1 {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}

.itemBebida1:hover {
    background-color: var(--DarkBlue);
}


/* TOP DIV */


/* Top Box 1 = Logo Recanto
Top Box 2 = Mesa
Top Box 3 = Pesquisa
Top Box 4 = Conta
Top Box 5 = Pedidos  */

.top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #123B79;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
}

.topBox1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 8;
}

.topBox2,
.topBox3,
.topBox4,
.topBox5 {
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 1;
}

.topBox2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.topBox3,
.topBox4,
.topBox5 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #2fa9ab;
    background-color: var(--LightBlue);
}

.topBox2:hover {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: #dadada;
}

.topBox3:hover,
.topBox4:hover,
.topBox5:hover {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: #4eb9bb;
    border-right: none;
}

.imgTopBox1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 19%;
    height: 100%;
}

#logoRecanto {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90%;
}

#mesaIMG,
#pesquisarIMG,
#contaIMG,
#pedidosIMG {
    width: 20%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    object-fit: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#mesaIMG {
    filter: invert(0%) sepia(9%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(130deg) brightness(0%) contrast(0%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./imgs/HMSC_Catavento.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Restaurante Recanto </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="./imgs/Prato_Content_5.png-" id="img_Content">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="itemDestaque">
                <img src="./imgs/Destaque.png" id="destaqueIMG">
                <br><span> DESTAQUE</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemCardapio" id="itemCardapio">
                <img src="./imgs/Cardapio2.png" id="cardapioIMG">
                <br><span> CARDÁPIO </span>
                <div class="leftCardapio">
                    <div class="itemPratos"></div>
                    <div class="itemSaladas"></div>
                    <div class="itemSopas"></div>
                    <div class="itemSobremesas"></div>
                    <div class="itemMolhos"></div>
                    <div class="itemPorcoes"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="itemBebidas">
                <img src="./imgs/Bebidas.png" id="bebidasIMG">
                <br><span> BEBIDAS </span>
                <div class="leftBebidas">
                    <div class="itemBebida1"></div>
                    <div class="itemBebida1"></div>
                    <div class="itemBebida1"></div>
                    <div class="itemBebida1"></div>
                    <div class="itemBebida1"></div>
                    <div class="itemBebida1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="itemReservar_mesa">
                <img src="./imgs/Mesa.png" id="reservar_mesaIMG">
                <br><span> RESERVAR MESA </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="topBox1">
                <div class="imgTopBox1">
                    <img src="./imgs/LogoRecanto.png" id="logoRecanto">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="topBox2">
                <img src="./imgs/Mesa.png" id="mesaIMG">
            </div>
            <div class="topBox3">
                <img src="./imgs/Pesquisar.png" id="pesquisarIMG">
            </div>
            <div class="topBox4">
                <img src="./imgs/Conta.png" id="contaIMG">
            </div>
            <div class="topBox5">
                <img src="./imgs/Pedidos.png" id="pedidosIMG">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <script src="./scripts/changeImg.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-menu elements increase in height when you zoom because that's the expected behavior of the zoom. Try zooming on any site or even here on stack-overflow.

When you zoom in browser what happens is that your visible area dimensions decrease. For example lets say your page is 1000px wide, when you zoom in to 200% it's now 500px wide, but these 500px are stretched to 1000px on your monitor.

On your site everything except sub-menu has % width and height. So if element width is 10% on 1000px screen it's 100px. If you zoom to 200% it's 10% of 500px, so 50px. Visually it stays the same size. Now when you have fixed dimensions on element like you have on your sub-menu, 80px is still 80px no matter how much you zoom in. On 500px screen of course 80px element will take more space then on 1000px screen.

[image]

Note the **80px height**